# Android Espresso Recorder not recording Android TV events

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

**Android Studio Build:**
Android Studio 2.2
Build #AI-145.3276617, built on September 15, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

**Version of Espresso:** 2.2.2

**Android version on the recording device/emulator:** Android M Nvidia Shield

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Select Run
2. Select Espresso test recorder
3. App starts
4. But recording only back event of DPAD.

**Required Updated:**

It should record all the DPAD events so that its useful for generating Android TV Espresso test.

Is Android TV espresso test recorder supported yet?

Comment: Filed following bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223698&thanks=223698&ts=1474872790

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this or did you give up on using the recorder?